# Why add an additional event handler for Page.InitComplete?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, web-parts, page-lifecycle

I'm learning about Web Parts and in one point the tutorial says to do the following in Page_Init:

```
Page.InitComplete += new EventHandler(GenerateModeList);
```

The tutorial proceeds to define GenerateModeList where a list of items is added to a DropDownList. This list will consist of supported Display Modes.

It seems to me that it would be simpler to define GenerateModeList method and call it from Page_InitComplete.

Why would I want to add an additional event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the *"GenerateModeList"* method needs access to the initialized controls (like the DropDownList).  The controls on the page have not been initialized at the point of `Page.Init`.

See the documentation on the [Page.InitComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.initcomplete.aspx) event:

> At this stage of the page's life cycle, all declared controls on the page are initialized, but the page's state is not yet populated. You can access server controls, but they will not yet contain information returned from the user.

Comment: As I said, the list gets populated with the supported display modes. But is there any real difference between adding an event handler as described in my question and simply calling that event handler manually from Page.InitComplete? The GenerateModeList method didn't have any need for any of the arguments that were handed to it (object source, EventArgs args). The author could've defined it as having no arguments, called it from Page.InitComplete and everything would work the same.

Comment: @robotron I misunderstood you.  I agree with you, can't see a reason either; maybe the author prefers to bind events explicitly (for reasons of pedagogy or coding standards) rather than relying on auto-event wireup (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.autoeventwireup.aspx).